# NSFetchRequest autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, autorelease, pool

First off I have to say this website and its members are amazing in their responses. Most helpful. thank you.

Secondly, I am troubleshooting the following error while troubleshooting an iPhone/iPad app that I am working on:

**NSFetchRequest autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking.**

the culprit code seems to be

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
```

found in this method

```
-(NSArray *)searchDatabase:(int)uniqueID withPredicate:(NSString *)pred{

NSLog(@": DetailViewController/searchDatabase() method...executing. ");
NSLog(@": DetailViewController/searchDatabase() pred = %@",pred); // returns ParentID

NSError *error = nil;
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Directory" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
//: moved above line
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", pred, [NSNumber numberWithInt:uniqueID]]];



NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:predicate];



//: get the session and update the record with the time it ended  
NSArray *mutableFetchResults = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@": DetailViewController/searchDatabase() mutableFetchResults = %@",mutableFetchResults);

[request release];
[error release];

NSLog(@": DetailViewController/searchDatabase() method...terminating.");    
return mutableFetchResults;

}
```

I am not sure if the release statements are properly set up, but even still I am unsure while the error shows up in the first place. I am a little new to objective c, and at compile time the application did not indicate any errors (the message shows up at runtime).

If anyone can help me out with this, it would be most appreciated.

thanks

Edward

Comment: Just an additional note - the purpose of this method is to simply retrieve some information from core Data to display in a menu. we search by the value of pred.

Comment: do you execute this in the main thread? Or in a separate one? In the latter case, you need to allocate an AutoReleasePool. But I also had that problem when in my custom View* (didload, unload etc.), I forgot to call the corresponding methods in super.

Comment: hi angrest (and others). the method is indeed called in a number of places - in ViewDidLoad() - it reads [finalArray setArray:[self searchDatabase:[self.num intValue] withPredicate:@"ParentID"]]; , in update() and didSelectRowAtIndexTablePath() in my DetailViewController.m (which I suppose is our custom view) . So I am supposing this is in the main thread (I don't recall creating threads) . Can you also clarify about calling the corresponding methods in super? for which method? thanks again

Comment: this appears to be correct. personally I never release errors, should I ?

Comment: Hi Julien, you could release error, it doesn't break the app.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right code? The fetch request is not released here, but a lot of other objects are. If there wasn't an autorelease pool, you would get warnings for them too. Check other places where you use a fetch request.